# Свойство Resources пустое

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml, resources

Я создаю приложение wpf и у меня есть вот такие строчки кода:

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    Background = (Brush)FindResource("Background");
}
```

Вот файл с окном:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="450" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/MainWindow.xaml"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

А вот сам словарь:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp">
    <ImageBrush x:Key="Background" ImageSource="Sources/..."/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Мой фон не определяет. Т. е. изменения не применяются. Но если сделать вот так:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="450" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Background="{StaticResource Background}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/MainWindow.xaml"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

то всё заработает. Как это пофиксить, чтоб работало и в коде, и в разметке. Когда отлаживал оказалось, что `Count` у свойства `Resources` равно нулю. Всё оч. странно.

Comment: Это весь код в `public MainWindow()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить `InitializeComponent` в `MainWindow()` и все заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Знаю два способа получения ресурсов в коде.

**Первый**:

```
var myResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
    myResourceDictionary.Source =
        new Uri("/DllName;component/MainWindow.xaml",
                UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

А затем получить по имени:

```
myResourceDictionary["Background"] as ImageBrush
```

**Второй:**

```
var imageBrush = (ImageBrush )Application.Current.FindResource("Background")
```

Второй способ подходит если вы используете один файл ресурсов в приложении.

А первый, если вы используете файл ресурсов в каком-то проекте один, а приложение использует другой файл ресурсов.

Comment: Ни один из способов не делает то, что мне нужно: изменение фона.

Comment: @return Давай так: как называется твой файл ресурсов и лежит ли он в какой-нибудь папке? Потому что я сейчас сделал так, как у тебя в описании и всё окей.

Comment: Ещё может быть такой момент: У тебя в ресурсах картинка хранится?

Comment: Путь к файлу ресурсов: `Resources/MainWindow.xaml`. Путь к картинке: `Resources/Sources/Background.jpg` (это сделано для того, чтобы отделить файлы ресурсов от файлов сурсов). Почему-то в разметке всё работает, а в коде - нет.

Comment: @alloduh Оказалось, что конструктор (класса `MainWindow`) просто не вызывается. А это как понимать?(